# Issue Copying Code From JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I am trying to copy some code from jsfiddle, it's a radial loading bar. I wanted to put it into html/css files and mess with the code, but I can't seem to get it to work. It just shows up blank, not displaying anything. The JSFiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/d7vKd/. Thanks you for your help :)

Here is my exact copy of the HTML/Javascript put into an HTML document:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loaderCss.css">
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less');
less.refreshStyles();
window.randomize = function() {
    $('.radial-progress').attr('data-progress', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
$('.radial-progress').click(window.randomize);


</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="radial-progress" data-progress="0">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="mask full">
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mask half">
            <div class="fill"></div>
            <div class="fill fix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inset">
        <div class="percentage"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and the CSS file:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic);

.radial-progress {
    @circle-size: 120px;
    @circle-background: #d6dadc;
    @circle-color: #97a71d;
    @inset-size: 90px;
    @inset-color: #fbfbfb;
    @transition-length: 1s;
    @shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    @percentage-color: #97a71d;
    @percentage-font-size: 22px;
    @percentage-text-width: 57px;

    margin: 50px;
    width:  @circle-size;
    height: @circle-size;

    background-color: @circle-background;
    border-radius: 50%;
    .circle {
        .mask, .fill, .shadow {
            width:    @circle-size;
            height:   @circle-size;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: @shadow inset;
        }
        .mask, .fill {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            transition: -webkit-transform @transition-length;
            transition: -ms-transform @transition-length;
            transition: transform @transition-length;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .mask {
            clip: rect(0px, @circle-size, @circle-size, @circle-size/2);
            .fill {
                clip: rect(0px, @circle-size/2, @circle-size, 0px);
                background-color: @circle-color;
            }
        }
    }
    .inset {
        width:       @inset-size;
        height:      @inset-size;
        position:    absolute;
        margin-left: (@circle-size - @inset-size)/2;
        margin-top:  (@circle-size - @inset-size)/2;

        background-color: @inset-color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: @shadow;
        .percentage {
            width:       @percentage-text-width;
            position:    absolute;
            top:         (@inset-size - @percentage-font-size) / 2;
            left:        (@inset-size - @percentage-text-width) / 2;

            line-height: 1;
            text-align:  center;

            font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color:       @percentage-color;
            font-weight: 800;
            font-size:   @percentage-font-size;
        }
    }

    @i: 0;
    @increment: 180deg / 100;
    .loop (@i) when (@i <= 100) {
        &[data-progress="@{i}"] {
            .circle {
                .mask.full, .fill {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(@increment * @i);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(@increment * @i);
                    transform: rotate(@increment * @i);
                }   
                .fill.fix {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(@increment * @i * 2);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(@increment * @i * 2);
                    transform: rotate(@increment * @i * 2);
                }
            }
            .inset .percentage:before {
                content: "@{i}%"
            }
        }
        .loop(@i + 1);
    }
    .loop(@i);
}
```

Comment: Why is your style `<link>` element *before* the `<head>`?

Comment: You are not including the script that provides the `less` variable. Also, since your document does not contain a `style` element, the first line of JS doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less');
```

This does nothing because you have no `<style>` elements.

It also doesn't make any sense. If the style element contains LESS instead of CSS then it should be marked up correctly in the first place.

```
less.refreshStyles();
```

This throws a reference error because you haven't defined `less`, so the rest of the code wouldn't run.

If it did…

```
setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
```

This is unsafe. It makes assumptions about how long the rest of the page will take to load. You should use a ready handler instead.

```
$('.radial-progress').click(window.randomize);
```

This does nothing. There aren't any elements that are members of the class in the document when you run that code. You should put it in a ready handler.

Comment: This is copied directly from that fiddle. Why does the fiddle code work then?

Comment: You copied from the UI without understanding what JS Fiddle was doing with the data there. See https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPxO_hIky9B1L0kv00BLhHuZaY6r0xonv0B/image.png and https://www.evernote.com/l/AAO77LXYiG9K0p4zeHD3OsL-MOawc4W_Ut0B/image.png